# How to make flask server running in a VM externally available?

Tags: python, azure, flask

If I run my flask app on my local machine I get proper results by connecting to http://127.0.0.1:5000/report?id=1

But now I want to make it externally visible by deploying my flask in a VM in azure. I have opened the port 80 on my VM. And I'm running the flask app using this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

I'm still not able to connect to my flask server using this (assume the public IP address of my VM is x.x.x.x):

http://x.x.x.x:5000/report?id=1

Any suggestions how should I go ahead with it?

Edit: I'm able to psping my VM's public IP address on port 80.

Comment: can you ping the ip of your vm? make sure you are using bridged network adapter for you VM network settings?  this is a problem with reaching the ip of vm, you are running flask `app.run` correctly to make it externally visible... in windows I sometimes have to open up the connection manager and edit the adapter properties and enable or disable various checkboxes(mostly to do with "network discovery")

Comment: yes, when I psping my vm on port 80 I'm able to connect to it

Comment: what is psping? ping does not use port 80 so Im not sure what  you mean? can you ssh into your vm ip?

Comment: since ICMP is disabled in Azure, psping is the way to test the connection. You can read about it more here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mast/archive/2014/06/22/use-port-pings-instead-of-icmp-to-test-azure-vm-connectivity.aspx

Comment: oh i see ... so the VM is running azure? what is the host pc running?

Comment: its running Windows Server 2012

Comment: sorry I misunderstood the question ... I think this is specific to azure, I dont think I can help you much :/

Comment: You'll probably have to set up port forwarding on your router so that you can connect to it externally using your external IP and port, see here, it should apply http://www.instructables.com/id/Python-Web-Server-for-your-Raspberry-Pi/?ALLSTEPS

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't related to Flask, since you opened up your application to listen on *any* public IP (`0.0.0.0`).

Moreover you should do a proper port mapping in your azure configuration. Google said, you might have a look here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/

**EDIT**

Another idea, where some colleages often run into, is that you may have skype open which somewhat uses port 80/443 and therefore is blocking it. Shutdown skype if you do so or use a different port for your webapp.

Comment: I'm sorry, you should really check this again then.

Answer (score 1):

So here's the deal with Azure:
If you open a port from the Azure portal, the firewall in your VM STILL blocks that port. You have to manually go in and create a firewall setting in your VM to keep the port 5000 open for your flask server. Once that is done, you should be able to connect to it.